# Maven - how to add all required dependencies for hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I have downloaded the zip from the Hibernate website and we have a folder which contains all required jars.

But I want to to this with Maven. Do I need to check which are the required libraries for this Hibernate version and add them manually in the `pom.xml`?

Is there a way just to add hibernate and maven to add all required libraries itself?

Comment: `hibernate-core` search for in repository. add the dependency.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you want to use JPA with Hibernate, you only need a single Maven dependency. Refer to the [download page](http://hibernate.org/orm/downloads/#maven-repository):

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.10.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

This dependency will pull all the required other artifacts as transitive dependencies (like the JPA API, Hibernate Core and a lot of others).

This is the power of Maven. You don't need to add anything manually to the classpath or figure out yourself which jars you should add. One Maven dependency will declare as transitive dependencies everything that it needs.

Comment: This is deprecated, better to use hibernate-core instead https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager

Answer (score 7):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>5.0.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

[image: Red arrow]

Answer (score 6):

When specifying a dependency with pom.xml it won't be included into your dependencies library as you are expecting (a jar file). Here is a list of basic hibernate artifact ids that I use to include:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    <classifier>tests</classifier>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Replace the ${hibernate.version} with desired version or define a property with this identifier.

Answer (score 2):

Basic core implementation (including JPA) Hibernate configurations can be setup using the hibernate-core dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.16.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

and this will transitively pull the following dependencies,
[image]

Reference: http://hibernate.org/orm/releases/5.2/