# Hibernate Exception root caused java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry

Tags: hibernate, servlets

I'm getting this exception  [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1364)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1185)
    at jlc.db.service.RegisterService.register(RegisterService.java:11)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set your dependency to hibernate as compile.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you Alexandar  for answering but where to add this dependency ?I'm using servlets JSP, hibernate in Eclipse 2018 I'm working
In which file i have to add please help me

Comment: Pom.xml file if you are using maven.

Comment: I'm not using maven what is the another option?

Comment: package the hibernate jar in the WEB-INF/lib directory in your war file. You have a war file right ? You may need to add other jars as well, here is a list of all dependencies https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33720355/maven-how-to-add-all-required-dependencies-for-hibernate

Comment: I would advice you to use maven, it is easier in long run than managing your own dependencies.

Comment: Thank you Alexandar