# Error while creating EntityManagerFactory: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, database, jpa

I have a problem creating entity manager factory. I'm using JPA to connect to a postgres database. The "Java_Lab_4" doesn't seem like a valid persistence Unit Name.

I've tried naming the persistence unit name org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl, but it didn't help.

```
    package model;

    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;  
    import java.math.BigDecimal;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Properties;
    import java.util.TreeSet;
    import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
    import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
    import javax.persistence.Persistence;
    import javax.persistence.Query;


    public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Properties props = new Properties();

            props.put("openjpa.ConnectionURL", "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres");
            props.put("openjpa.ConnectionDriverName", "org.jdbc.Driver");
            props.put("openjpa.ConnectionUserName", "postgres");
            props.put("openjpa.ConnectionPassword", "stalker");
            props.put("openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings", "public");
    // the problem is here -->
            EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Java_Lab_4", props);
            saveEntities(emf);
            readEntities(emf);

        }

        private static void saveEntities(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
            EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
            em.getTransaction().begin();

            try {

                Booking booking = new Booking();
                booking.setBooking_Code(BigDecimal.valueOf(12345.0));
                booking.setPaid("yes");
                booking.setPassenger_Code(1234);
                booking.setFlight_Code(BigDecimal.valueOf(9999));
                booking.setDate(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("9/10/2019"));

                em.persist(booking);

                em.getTransaction().commit();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

                em.getTransaction().rollback();
            } finally {

                em.close();
            }
        }

        private static void readEntities(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
            EntityManager em;
            em = emf.createEntityManager();
            em.getTransaction().begin();

            try {

                Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT x FROM Group x");

                List<?> list = query.getResultList();

                if (!list.isEmpty()) {

                    for (Object object : list) {
                        Date date = ((Booking)list).getDate();
                        String paid = ((Booking)list).getPaid();
                        long passengerCode = ((Booking)list).getPassenger_Code();
                        BigDecimal flightCode = ((Booking)list).getFlight_Code();
                        BigDecimal bookingCode = ((Booking)list).getBooking_Code();
                        System.out.println("PassengerCode = " + passengerCode
                                + ", FlightCode = " + flightCode.toString() + ", BookingCode = " 
                                + bookingCode.toString() + ", Date = " + date.toString() 
                                + "Paid = " + paid);
                    }

                } else {
                    System.out.println("No booking");
                }

                em.getTransaction().commit();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

                em.getTransaction().rollback();
            } finally {

                em.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Persistence file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd" >
        <persistence-unit name="Java_Lab_4">
            <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
            <class>model.Booking</class>
            <class>model.Category</class>
            <class>model.Flight</class>
            <class>model.Passenger</class>
            <class>model.Ticket</class>
        </persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/logging/Logger
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.<clinit>(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProviderResolverHolder$DefaultPersistenceProviderResolver.getPersistenceProviders(PersistenceProviderResolverHolder.java:117)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:76)
    at model.Test.main(Test.java:26)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.logging.Logger
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: Its complaining about missing jar.Try adding https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging jar from here and run the application and share results.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong the EntityManagerFactory name - but you are missing a class on the classpath.

As mentioned in the comment on your question, you're going to need to add the jboss-logging jar file to your classpath.

BUT - Hibernate has LOTs of dependencies, so if you're putting the Jars together yourself then it's going to take you a long time to get them all, and in the right versions!

You can download a zip (70Mb) which contains the dependencies needed from here:

https://hibernate.org/orm/releases/5.4/

(use the "download zip archive" button, right hand side - it's not that easy to see!)

The jars are in the "lib" folder, there's then several subfolders - for now at least I would just throw all of these onto your classpath, except for the optional folder.

If you're at all familiar with Maven or similar (Gradle, whatever), then I'd recommend using that, then most of the dependencies will be downloaded automatically, there's guidance in the question here: [Maven - how to add all required dependencies for hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33720355/maven-how-to-add-all-required-dependencies-for-hibernate)

Comment: I put all the jars from the hibernate zip except for optional, but I still get the error: Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named Java_Lab_4
 at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:85)
 at model.Test.main(Test.java:26)

Comment: @DimitriDoroshko that's a different error. So that's good, it's progress. Raise a new question with the new problem. There's not enough there to diagnose, "no persistence provider" is a bit of a catch-all that could be caused by many things. But it's likely some minor configuration, so don't give up.